# Get the last value of each date and pivot table based on field value in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the last value of each group in 'FIELD_NAME' based on a timestamp 'FIELD_TIME' using Snowflake.

I have the following table,

[image]

I would like the table to have one column to each value (e.g., Number of Products, Date of SKU Live..etc) and that column only has the last value of that day. Like the following table,

| ISSUE_ID | ISSUE_ID | FIELD_TIME | Number of Products | Number of SKU live | Date of SKU Live | Number of SKU Not Created | Work_In_Progress_Date | Pending_Date | Status | Resolution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19229 | X1 | 2021-08-01 | 55 | 21 | 2021-08-01 | 34 |  |  | PENDING | Null |
| 19229 | X1 | 2021-08-08 |  |  |  |  |  |  | PENDING | Null |
| 19229 | X1 | 2021-08-12 | 55 | 24 | 2021-08-01 | 31 | 2021-08-12 | 2021-08-12 | PENDING | Null |

I have tried `last_value(FIELD_VALUE) over (partition by FIELD_NAME, ISSUE_ID order by field_time)` but it gives me duplicated values with 23 rows and not 3 rows.
I have tried `lag()` as well with no luck.

Below is my code, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
 select
           t.ISSUE_ID, t.issue_name,
    --        t.created_date,
           t.field_time::date as field_time,
           max(case when field_name = 'Number of Products' then field_value end) as Number_of_Products,
           max(case when field_name = 'Number of SKU live' then field_value end) as Number_of_SKU_Live,
           max(case when field_name = 'Number of SKU not created' then field_value end) as Number_of_SKU_Not_Created,
           max(case when field_name = 'Date of SKU live' then field_value end) as Date_of_SKU_Live,
           max(case when field_value = '10020' then date(t.field_time) end) as Work_In_Progress_Date,
           max(case when field_value = '10010' then date(t.field_time) end) as Pending_Date,
           t.status, t.resolution
           from
    (select fh.ISSUE_ID,
           i.issue_name,
           date(i.created_date) as created_date,
           fh.TIME as field_time,
           f.name as field_name,
           fh.value as field_value,
           i.status,
           i.resolution
    from JIRA.ISSUE_FIELD_HISTORY fh
             left join JIRA.FIELD f on fh.FIELD_ID = f.ID and f._FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
             left join (select i0.created as created_date,r.name as resolution, i0.id, i0.key as issue_name, i0.status as status_id, s.name as status
                        from JIRA.issue i0
                                 left join JIRA.status s on i0.status = s.ID
                                 left join JIRA.RESOLUTION r on i0.RESOLUTION = r.ID
                 where i0._FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
                 and i0.key like 'PIM%')
                 i on i.id = fh.ISSUE_ID
    where fh.ISSUE_ID in (select ID from ISSUE where PROJECT = 10041)
    and fh.FIELD_ID in ('customfield_10067', 'customfield_10063', 'customfield_10066', 'customfield_10068', 'status', 'resolution')
    -- and issue_name = 'PIM-11'
    qualify row_number() over (partition by issue_id, field_time::date, field_name order by field_time desc) = 1
    order by field_time) t
    group by issue_id, issue_name,created_date, field_time::date, status, resolution
```

The tables used are,

- ISSUE_FIELD_HISTORY: the main table used to link field-related columns.
- FIELD: secondary table to get the field name associated with the field id.
- ISSUE: secondary table to get issue name, id, and status id as well related to each issue.
- STATUS: to get the staus name related to staus id in the ISSUE table.
- RESOLUTION: to get the resolution status (resolution name).

Comment: Your sample data and desired results have nothing to do with each other.  Your query refers to a bunch of tables and columns that are not defined.

Comment: I added a description to each table used.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your query because there are too many tables for which you haven't given the definitions. However, based on your requirements, here is a simplified example using PIVOT that would give the expected results:

```
with cte as (
select 19229 as issue_id, 'X1' as issue_name, '2021-08-01 09:04:35'::timestamp_ntz as field_time, 'Status' as field_name, 10020 as field_value, 'Work In Progress' as status union all
select 19229 as issue_id, 'X1' as issue_name, '2021-08-01 09:04:35'::timestamp_ntz as field_time, 'Number of Products' as field_name, 55 as field_value, 'PENDING' as status union all
select 19229 as issue_id, 'X1' as issue_name, '2021-08-01 09:04:35'::timestamp_ntz as field_time, 'Number of SKU live' as field_name, 21 as field_value, 'PENDING' as status union all
select 19229 as issue_id, 'X1' as issue_name, '2021-08-08 06:19:05'::timestamp_ntz as field_time, 'Status' as field_name, 10010 as field_value, 'PENDING' as status
),
t as (
select ISSUE_ID,
           issue_name,
           field_time::date as field_date,
           field_name,
           field_value,
           last_value(status) over (partition by issue_id, field_time::date order by field_time desc) as last_status
    from cte
    qualify row_number() over (partition by issue_id, field_time::date, field_name order by field_time desc) = 1
)
select * from t
pivot(max(field_value) for field_name in ('Status', 'Number of Products', 'Number of SKU live')) as p
order by field_date
;
```

You have to use last_value(status) in your query because the status changes during the day and may be different for each field_value. Here is the result of the query, giving one record per day with the latest values of each of the fields:

```
ISSUE_ID    ISSUE_NAME  FIELD_DATE  LAST_STATUS         'Status'    'Number of Products'    'Number of SKU live'
19229       X1          2021-08-01  Work In Progress    10020       55                      21
19229       X1          2021-08-08  PENDING             10010
```

Comment: the code is running and it's giving me all values of each group in 'field_value', yet I couldn't get the two columns 'Work_In_Progress_Date' and 'Pending_Date'. I would like the final table to include when the issue was 'Work_In_progress' and when it was shifted to 'Pending'. Thank you

Comment: Your requirement was "I would like the table to have one column to each value (e.g., Number of Products, Date of SKU Live..etc) and that column only has the last value of that day." so I understood that you want only one record per day. If you want all statuses, then just change this line in the query: "last_value(status) over (partition by issue_id, field_time::date order by field_time desc) as last_status" to "status".

Comment: In the desired outcome if you scroll to right there are two columns 'Work_In_Progress_Date' and 'Pending_Date' both should have one value per day that is the field_date for which the status value was either 10010 or 10020. Those two I couldn't really return them as a date. Appreicated your patience and help.